# What is the "-DranSHR3" option for in the mex compiler

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

I have seen [several](http://goo.gl/hAhHk) Matlab contributions at the Mathworks' file exchange site where the authors use the option "-DranSHR3" when compiling with mex. I checked the [mex](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html), the GNU [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Index.html#Option-Index)  and the Microsoft's [cl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx) documentations, but found nothing.

Any thoughts on what this option is used for? Where can I find more details about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `-DranSHR3` defines the preprocessor Symbol `ranSHR3` which in turn selects the SHR3 random generator instead of the default one.

[Here](http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/65522) you can read about Matlab's random generators.

[Here](http://cljanss.bitbucket.org/rng_8h_source.html) I found a somewhat long comment about SHR3.

At least in Matlab R2010b the default generator for random streams is Mersenne Twister which is a very good choice. SHR3 compared to Mersenne Twister could be faster, I don't know. What is sure is that SHR3 has worse random properties than Mersenne Twister, for starters it has a shorter period of 2^64 instead of MT's 2^19936-1. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randstream.list.html) is the corresponding Matlab documentation.

Perhaps the popularity of SHR3 stems from older versions where Mersenne Twister wasn't the default or for compatibility?

Comment: Thanks @Peter G. Why is SHR3 more popular than the default random generator? Where can I learn more about this?

Answer (score 1):

`-D` is usually used to set a macro: it should be equivalent to putting a

```
#define ranSHR3
```

in any source file.